# Insert a parameter to a function with a javascript event

Tags: javascript, html

I have a sequence of button groups that will change depending on what button was clicked before. I have the first group to choose the type of the piece the user is creating (for example a shirt or a hoodie), and depending on what type the user chooses it will generate a different group to choose its design.

To do that I created a button group with only one hidden button on my HTML file, when the user chooses a type a for loop creates the next group cloning the hidden button, displaying it, and inserting some text.

### JavaScript

```
var designs = {
    shirt : ['Simple', 'V-Neck', 'Polo'],
    hoodie : ['Sweater', 'Hoodie'],
}

function chooseType(type) {
    var btnGroup = document.getElementById('btn-group');
    var btn = document.getElementById('design-btn');

    for (k in designs){
        if (type == k) {
            for (i=0; i < designs[k].length; i++) {
                var clone = btn.cloneNode(true);
                btnGroup.appendChild(clone);
                clone.classList.remove('d-none');
                clone.innerHTML = designs[k][i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, in order to generate the next step, I would have to know what design the user chose to put it as a parameter on my `chooseDesign(design)` function on the same way I had `type` as a parameter on my `chooseType(type)` function.

### HTML

```
<div id="design" class="d-none">
    <p>Design da peça:</p>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="btn-group">
        <button onclick="chooseDesign()" type="button" class="d-none" id="design-btn"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to insert a different parameter on the `chooseDesign(design)` function to each button after it was cloned?

Comment: Consider using event delegation here. Instead of the function store the deign value in `data-design`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses event delegation to listen for clicks. NOTE: I had to add the Shirt and Hoodie to demonstrate.

```js
var designs = {
    shirt : ['Simple', 'V-Neck', 'Polo'],
    hoodie : ['Sweater', 'Hoodie'],
}   

const createButton = (style) => {
      let button = document.createElement('button');
      button.dataset.style = style;
      button.innerText = style;
      return button;
      }

function chooseType(type) {
    let btnGroup = document.getElementById('btn-group');
    btnGroup.innerHTML = "";

    designs[type].forEach(s => {
      btnGroup.appendChild(createButton(s));
    });
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('.design-select')) {
    chooseType(e.target.id);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="design" class="d-none">
    <p>Design da peça:</p>
    <button id="shirt" class="design-select">Shirt</button>
    <button id="hoodie" class="design-select">Hoodie</button>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="btn-group">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I liked the idea of using event delegation, but I still don't understand how I'll know what kind of shirt the user chose since the buttons were cloned and don't have unique ids for them.

Comment: Notice in the code, as we create the buttons we add the `data-style` value. This stores the style.

Comment: So in the code above, the user `clicks` Shirt. We build out a button array for styles in shirt. Adding the style value to each button. So we do know. (although you probably want to use something other than buttons)